# How to run antlr code in python and validate my input

Tags: python, antlr

I have a simple grammar file hello.g contains

```
grammar Hello_world;
utterance : greeting | exclamation;
greeting : interjection subject;
exclamation : 'Hooray!';
interjection : 'Hello';
subject : 'World!';
```

which validates strings 'Hello World!' and 'Hooray!'

But How to test this grammar? Somewhere I read we need to compile the parser and others. I am new to ANTLR, please help.

I used AntlrWorks1.5 to generate the lexer and parser;
After that used the below code to run the test:

```
import antlr3
from helloworldLexer import helloworldLexer
from helloworldParser import helloworldParser

while True:
    expr = raw_input('>>> ')
    if expr == '':
        break

    cStream = antlr3.StringStream(expr)
    lexer = helloworldLexer(cStream)
    tStream = antlr3.CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = helloworldParser(tStream)
    result = parser.evaluate()
    print result
```

When I run the above python file, got the below error:

```
>>> Hello World!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\workspace\antlr\output\hello.py", line 12, in <module>
    lexer = helloworldLexer(cStream)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\workspace\antlr\output\helloworldLexer.py", line 26, in __init__
    state = RecognizerSharedState()
NameError: global name 'RecognizerSharedState' is not defined
```

Comment: In one of your previous questions I linked to two answers that demonstrates how get ANTLR to work with Python.

Comment: @BartKiers, I have added a test suite and error output of my grammar. I am not able to find out what the error exactly is!